# How work target_include_directories cmake for include the local library how <path/lib.h>

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using external files for work with my library, so but I do not want using the relative path inside my file C++ but I want using this convention

I read that with CMake is possible to create this if using the [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) 
I'm new with Cmake and I have a problem with configuring this target on my project

This is my directory configuration

[image]

This is my CMake configuration

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(decompile-bitcoin-script)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    set(SOURCE_FILES 
            main.cpp

            #Bitcoin Lib
            bitcoinlib/script.cpp
            bitcoinlib/script_error.cpp
            bitcoinlib/key_io.cpp
            bitcoinlib/pubkey.cpp
            bitcoinlib/sign.cpp
            bitcoinlib/standard.cpp
        )

    add_executable(Decompiler ${SOURCE_FILES})

    target_include_directories(Decompiler PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/bitcoinlib)
```

This is the compiler error

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/bitcoinlib/script.cpp.o
/home/vincenzo/Github/decompiler-bitcoin-script/bitcoinlib/script.cpp:6:10: fatal error: bitcoinlib/script.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bitcoinlib/script.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/bitcoinlib/script.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/bitcoinlib/script.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Decompiler.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Inside the main not have code but I have only main with a `cout<<"foo";`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cmake
target_include_directories(Decompiler PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/bitcoinlib)
```

This line is telling the compiler that `./bitcoinlib` is the root of the include path.

So `#include <bitcoinlib/script.h>` is looking for `./bitcoinlib/bitcoinlib/script.h`.

You seem to have set up your project directory with `CMakeLists.txt` *inside* your source/headers directory, so you can change the `target_include_directories` setting like this:

```cmake
target_include_directories(Decompiler PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)
```

Or, you can change `./bitcoinlib/script.cpp` to `#include <script.h>` since that header is in the same directory as the .cpp file anyways.

---

I would recommend that you restructure your project a bit though:

```plaintext
<Project Directory>
    CMakeLists.txt
    include
        bitcoinlib
            < your bitcoinlib headers here >
    src
        bitcoinlib
            < your bitcoinlib sources here >
        main.cpp
```

```cmake
target_include_directories(Decompiler PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarification